# Автоматизация постов в jekyll

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, github

Делаю блог на *github*-e с помощью *jekyll*-a.

Как автоматизировать написание постов, не писать каждый раз дату в названии файла, или первые три строчки (как в *hexo.io*, или *octopress*)?

---

**примечание от редактора**: далее — второй вопрос, который следовало бы задать отдельно.

В маленьких постах, например, каком-нибудь цитатнике, краткие названия, они же *slug*-и, не имеют смысла и лишь засоряют *url*.

Как сделать так, чтобы в *url* отображался *id* записи, а не *slug*?

---

Документацию читал, но про это ничего не сказано, видимо, всем нравится писать всё вручную, или же я не умею гуглить (что вероятнее всего).

Comment: Ответ на первый вопрос -- никак, для постов дата обязательна. Встречный вопрос -- что, собстна,надо автоматизировать. Создание файла с валидным содержимым, чтобы сразу писать там пост? А что касается id -- в Jekyll такого нет, за ненадобностью.

Comment: Вообще-то даты в названии плодятся самим джекилом при старте, когда я делал нечто похожее, я ничего не писал, только называния статей. Чтобы slug не отображался попробуйте поиграть со служебными полями документа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По первому вопросу можно использовать gem [jekyll-compose](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-compose)